# Using a Model function in Controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my model named `Profile_model` I have this function which retrieves profile data for the logged in user.

```
function profile_read()
{
    $this->db->where('user_id', $this->tank_auth->get_user_id());
    $query = $this->db->get('user_profiles');
    $data['row'] = $query->row();
}
```

In my controller I'm using `$this->load->view('profile/edit_general_view', $data);` to try and load the data from the model into the view.

```
function edit_profile()
{       

    //validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[2]|max_length[20]|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[2]|max_length[20]|alpha');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) //if validation rule fails
    {           
        $this->load->view('profile/edit_general_view', $data); //load data from model in view
    }
    else //success
    {
        $send_to_db = array (                   
                'first_name'    => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name'     => $this->input->post('last_name')
        );
        $seg = 'edit';
        $this->load->model('Profile_model');
        $this->Profile_model->profile_update($send_to_db, $seg);            
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to pass the data from the model function `profile_read` into my controller function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time to read about variable scopes:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

The $data variable in the model method isn't accessible to the controller. Have the model method return an actual array of data.. eg:

```
function profile_read()
{
    $this->db->where('user_id', $this->tank_auth->get_user_id());
    $query = $this->db->get('user_profiles');
    return ($query ? $query->row : FALSE);
}
```

And then in the controller, store that in the 'data' for the view.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Time to also read about [returning values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php). @CyberJunkie, this is just rudimentary PHP, just so you know it's not necessarily Codeigniter related.

Comment: Thanks! now I was able to use the model function in controller using `$this->load->model('Profile_model');
  $data['row'] = $this->Profile_model->profile_read();`